# Why does pip claim that I have an incompatible module despite a correct version (and breaks a docker build)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker, pip, python-module

When building a script in a docker container I need to install external libraries. One of them fails:

```
Step 2/6 : RUN pip install paho-mqtt logbook arrow requests ics
 ---> Running in 93d9144d6224
(...)

ERROR: ics 0.5 has requirement arrow<0.12,>=0.11, but you'll have arrow 0.15.2 which is incompatible.
Installing collected packages: paho-mqtt, logbook, six, python-dateutil, arrow, chardet, certifi, urllib3, idna, requests, ics
Successfully installed arrow-0.15.2 certifi-2019.9.11 chardet-3.0.4 ics-0.5 idna-2.8 logbook-1.5.2 paho-mqtt-1.4.0 python-dateutil-2.8.0 requests-2.22.0 six-1.12.0 urllib3-1.25.5
```

I do not understand this error:

- the versions seem to be OK: 0.15.2 >= 0.11
- despite the error the installation is "successful"

In any case (weather the installation is successful or not) this error breaks the docker build.

**The main question would be why the error is there in the first place?**

The sub-questions:

- how to fix it?
- if the build is successful, how to force at least temporarily the docker build (this is a home setup)

---

The whole build log in case there are other useful information:

```
Step 1/6 : FROM python:3.7-alpine
 ---> 39fb80313465
Step 2/6 : RUN pip install paho-mqtt logbook arrow requests ics
 ---> Running in 93d9144d6224
Collecting paho-mqtt
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/25/63/db25e62979c2a716a74950c9ed658dce431b5cb01fde29eb6cba9489a904/paho-mqtt-1.4.0.tar.gz (88kB)
Collecting logbook
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/6b/3f/f4e6693791efacc1282852fba5392da0649b19416b37422c5489f79a52ea/Logbook-1.5.2.tar.gz (85kB)
Collecting arrow
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/cc/f5/f618f8423fe674a60461e58683edfeead93f4bbf95b9fca0e9699e765b35/arrow-0.15.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (40kB)
Collecting requests
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/51/bd/23c926cd341ea6b7dd0b2a00aba99ae0f828be89d72b2190f27c11d4b7fb/requests-2.22.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (57kB)
Collecting ics
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/3a/66/7844baa915da9a76ef7b7b6d93935cc1474688c6ea914b90dbe54d6f6f41/ics-0.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting python-dateutil (from arrow)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/41/17/c62faccbfbd163c7f57f3844689e3a78bae1f403648a6afb1d0866d87fbb/python_dateutil-2.8.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (226kB)
Collecting chardet<3.1.0,>=3.0.2 (from requests)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/bc/a9/01ffebfb562e4274b6487b4bb1ddec7ca55ec7510b22e4c51f14098443b8/chardet-3.0.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (133kB)
Collecting certifi>=2017.4.17 (from requests)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/18/b0/8146a4f8dd402f60744fa380bc73ca47303cccf8b9190fd16a827281eac2/certifi-2019.9.11-py2.py3-none-any.whl (154kB)
Collecting urllib3!=1.25.0,!=1.25.1,<1.26,>=1.21.1 (from requests)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/81/b7/cef47224900ca67078ed6e2db51342796007433ad38329558f56a15255f5/urllib3-1.25.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl (125kB)
Collecting idna<2.9,>=2.5 (from requests)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/14/2c/cd551d81dbe15200be1cf41cd03869a46fe7226e7450af7a6545bfc474c9/idna-2.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl (58kB)
Collecting six>1.5 (from ics)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/73/fb/00a976f728d0d1fecfe898238ce23f502a721c0ac0ecfedb80e0d88c64e9/six-1.12.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Building wheels for collected packages: paho-mqtt, logbook
  Building wheel for paho-mqtt (setup.py): started
  Building wheel for paho-mqtt (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
  Created wheel for paho-mqtt: filename=paho_mqtt-1.4.0-cp37-none-any.whl size=48332 sha256=56275b1fa3496506436d27287c83cde7c59ec350292f87edd45f0248f8ef46e5
  Stored in directory: /root/.cache/pip/wheels/82/e5/de/d90d0f397648a1b58ffeea1b5742ac8c77f71fd43b550fa5a5
  Building wheel for logbook (setup.py): started
  Building wheel for logbook (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
  Created wheel for logbook: filename=Logbook-1.5.2-cp37-cp37m-linux_x86_64.whl size=66345 sha256=1a1f099a9baeaab15f43814c6506f3fc640c49add0fb8fafeb93397de9cd34b6
  Stored in directory: /root/.cache/pip/wheels/c7/d6/22/9f6bd2884a48b215fdd9cbfa78671b51f4470dfd3d14ef701a
Successfully built paho-mqtt logbook
ERROR: ics 0.5 has requirement arrow<0.12,>=0.11, but you'll have arrow 0.15.2 which is incompatible.
Installing collected packages: paho-mqtt, logbook, six, python-dateutil, arrow, chardet, certifi, urllib3, idna, requests, ics
Successfully installed arrow-0.15.2 certifi-2019.9.11 chardet-3.0.4 ics-0.5 idna-2.8 logbook-1.5.2 paho-mqtt-1.4.0 python-dateutil-2.8.0 requests-2.22.0 six-1.12.0 urllib3-1.25.5
Removing intermediate container 93d9144d6224
 ---> 7a3f016d1374
```

Comment: The requirement is `arrow<0.12,>=0.11`, not just `>=0.11`

Comment: @roganjosh: ahhh, you are right. I read the error from left to right, assuming that the left side is for lower values. I did not realize it was a bracket (the version must be between 0.11 and 0.12). If you turn your comment into an answer I will gladly accept it.

Comment: :S I can't do anything other than point out the upper bound on the restriction, it's a long way from presenting you with a fix. You should probably leave the question open for now to see if anyone has more input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing your `Dockerfile` we can't really see what you are doing; but

```
pip install arrow==0.11
```

instead of `pip install arrow` should fix the immediate problem.

If the commands in your `RUN` statements are separated with `&&` you can change that to `;` after the command whose error you want to ignore, and you can add `|| true` at the end to make the entire `RUN` statement always succeed; but this is generally poor practice, and in this case, it's unlikely to produce a useful image anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You have a module named `ics` which has dependency on the `arrow` module with version `<0.12,>=0.11`, these versions of the dependencies are specified when you build a python module. While building your docker image it is using  `arrow 0.15.2` from the cache, since it might be already installed on your computer.

Best way to deal with these types of errors is to define all your dependencies with their versions in a `requirements.txt` file and run `pip install -r requirements.txt` to install all in one go.

I can't say for sure why your build is failing though. You can try to uninstall the `arrow` module and reinstall the specified version.